Restoring view model state when navigating back
I have a question about how to handle back navigation for a specific situation in my project. The basics look something like this:
I have a tutorial (written all in Compose) that's split into three distinct sections, each section with its own view model and nav graph. Here's a loose representation of what it looks like:
@Composable
Section1HostScreen() {
    val section1VM: Section1ViewModel
    NavHost() {
        composable<ScreenA>
        composable<ScreenB>
        composable<ScreenC>
        composable<ScreenD>
        composable<Section2HostScreen>
    }
}

Once we navigate to the Section2HostScreen we get a similar setup to the first section's host screen, with a Section2ViewModel and a series of screens that will then get to section 3's host screen.
The issue I'm having is that if a user navigates back from section 2's initial Screen E, I'd like them to be able to go back to ScreenD in section 1 with the UI state how they left it, which isn't working at the moment because the view model is now gone.
What is the best way to achieve this? The only constraint that I have is that I'm required to have the view models be separate, so I can't have one view model to govern the entire tutorial flow due to bloat and difficulty solving merge conflicts when multiple people make changes. Thanks for any help.

You will have a very deep backStack with your current setup. Imagine what the navigation graph would look like if you have 10, 15 sections. I suggest you use nested graphs or have a parent NavHost that hosts all sections, and pass the navigation logic to the first and last screens of every section.
Regarding retaining UI state, if you want to preserve UI state "permanently" (i.e. user come back to Screen1 from, for example, Screen7 and still have the same state), you can implement a small database or DataStore for simple values and simply have your ViewModel fetch the state from it. If you only want to retain simple state across back-to-back screen then you can implement SavedStateHandle for your ViewModel
